# I'm having trouble running a (AWS batch) that requires a parameter called ContainerOverrides

Tags: java, aws-batch

Build a solution at the java code level which is consumed by an AWS service called batch, it asks me for the following parameters:

- custom job name
- queue name
- job definition
- finally a **command** (this command tells me the AWS documentation that I should work with the following method)

**withContainerOverrides**("Here you receive a value of type ContainerOverrides")

*My problem is the following; I send the value that it requests, when inserting said "value" it is modified a bit by the theme that has double quotes, but even so the id accepts the syntax of the java code, once it is executed in the environment, I get the following error inside cloudWatch*

LOG - CloudWatch

> python: can't open file
> '/app/["main.py","--file","sql_scripts/test_test.sql"]': [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory

This is the code that I have implemented

```
AWSBatch client = AWSBatchClientBuilder.standard().build();
         ContainerOverrides command = new ContainerOverrides().withCommand("[\"main.py\",\"--file\",\"sql_scripts/test_test.sql\"]");
        SubmitJobRequest request = new SubmitJobRequest()
                .withJobName("test-Automation")
                .withJobQueue("test-Queue")
                .withJobDefinition("test-Batch")
                .withContainerOverrides(command); //no string - yes value type ContainerOverrides
        SubmitJobResult response = client.submitJob(request);
        LOGGER.info("Response {} : ", response);
        String idBatch = response.getJobId();
```

I hope that when executing this code, the AWS batch service will tell me in the console that it is in a running state

Comment: Find the solution is the following: 

 List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add("main.py");
        command.add("--file");
        command.add("sql_scripts/test_test.sql");

System.out.println("response: " command);

console response: ["main.py","--file","sql_scripts/test_test.sql"]